# Find the expectation of vertices

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, expected-value

Question: A point is chosen *uniformly* at random from the triangle in the plane with vertices (0,0), (1,0), (0,2). Let *X* be the x-coordinate of this point, and let *Y* be the y-coordinate of this point.

$$Compute: E(XY^2)$$

I know that $E(XY^2) = E(X)*E(Y^2)$ but I don't know how to compute these two numbers. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Your $(X,Y)$ are distributed uniform over that triangle $T$. Can you write down their pdf $f(x,y)$? (Remember that $\iint_T f(x,y) dxdy = 1.$)

After you do that, the result is
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[XY^2\right] = \iint_T xy^2 f(x,y)dxdy.
$$